# prove that $A^n$=$0$ for some integer $n$

Tags: matrices

Suppose that, $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ such that $a_i$$_j$$=$$0$ for $i$$\geq$$j.$

Prove that,$A^n$=$0$.

Comment: Is the use of $n$ as both the order of the matrix and the exponent in the equation $A^n = 0$ purposeful?

Comment: yeah...may b...

Comment: What can you say about the shape of $A^k$? Look at an example to see what exactly is going on, then prove that stronger fact, perhaps by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof I.** The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
p_A(\lambda)=\det (A-xI)=
\det\,\left(\begin{matrix}
-x & a_{12} & a_{13} &\cdots & a_{1n}\\
0 & -x & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots& & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x
\end{matrix}\right)=(-x)^n,
$$
which due to [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) implies that $A^n=0$.

**Proof II.** One can show that, if $A^2=(A^2_{ij})$, then $A_{ij}^2=0$ if $i+2\ge j$, and inductively that if $A^k=(A^k_{ij})$, then $A_{ij}^k=0$ if $i+k\ge j$, and hence $A^n_{ij}=0$, for all $i,j$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hints:**
One way is to employ of [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem): $A$ is an upper triangular matrix with diagonal $0,$ hence with the characteristic polynomial$=(-x)^n.$
Another is by induction: show that, if $A^m=(a^{(m)}_{ij}),$ then $a^{(m)}_{ij}=0, \forall i\ge j-m+1, $ for $m\ge1.$
Maybe there are other ways around; here are only two of them.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_i$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$ (or whatever field you're working with). Then $Ae_1=0$; $Ae_2= a_{12} e_1$ and so $A^2e=0$; $Ae_3=a_{13} e_1 + a_{23}e_2$ and so $A^3e_3=0$, etc. and so $A^n e_i=0$ for all $i$, which means $A^n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** what are the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Comment: 0...So then? What can be said about A^n?